# JavaFX application into runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, jar, runnable

I am trying to export my javaFX application into a runnable jar. Everything is doing well when the jar file is in my project's directory. But when I move it to the desktop the images are not showing anymore and the FileChooser does not respond.
I linked the ressource folder as source file.
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Please provide some source code parts. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Run your .jar file on the command line:  `java -jar MyApplication.jar`.  If an exception is displayed, edit your question and add the *entire stack trace* to it.